# vscode python gettext : Pylance reports undefined variable '_'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gettext

In a localized program I use gettext.install() in the main modul src/testgettext.py.

The documentation (python 3.10.7) says

> gettext.install(domain, localedir=None, codeset=None, names=None)
> This installs the function _() in Python’s builtins namespace...

The code

```
import gettext

gettext.install("any")

de = gettext.translation('testgettext',localedir="src/locales", languages=['de'])

de.install()

print(_("Selected Files:"))
```

functions as awaited, producing 'Ausgewählte Dateien:' from 'src/locales/de/LC_MESSAGES/testgettext.po'.

Nevertheless I get the warning
"_" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) ...
In my original main file this "problem" occures 85 times, cluttering any important problems.

Inserting
`_ = t.gettext` 
removes the pylance-problem-message, but only on module level.
python-gettext-docu:

> This puts _() only in the module’s global namespace and so only affects calls within this module.
> All other modules would have to be altered, too.

So my question:
what to do in order to use python gettext in vcode without unnecessary pylance warnings about '_()'?

BTW: in eclipse/pydev the code functions without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally [I found the answer](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/builtins.md):

> ...you may want to tell Pyright about these additional symbols that are available at runtime. To do so, you can add a local type stub file called `__builtins__.pyi`

Inserting a file called `__builtins__.pyi` with the contents `_ = str` in the base of the project will be interpreted by pyright so that `_` is evaluated as a global symbol of type `str`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with pylance's report that it cannot detect that `_` is defined by `gettext.install()` and therefore assumes it is an undefined variable.

You can indicate that this `_` is a function that returns a translated string by adding a type hint

```
from typing import Callable

def _(s: str) -> str:
    return s
```

Comment: Your suggestion offers no improvement from the documentations statements "This puts _() only in the module’s global namespace and so only affects calls within this module. All other modules would have to be altered, too."
Either I would await pylance to take in account gettexts install in global space, or it should be possible to exclude this object from checking.

Comment: Can you show a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Create a directory and open it with VScode, directory becomes ${workspaceFolder}
Create directory src/
Save the code shown above as src/testgettext.py
Create a message catalog src/locales/de/LC_MESSAGES/testgettext.mo, e.g. with poedit <https://poedit.net/>
Running src/testgettext.py outputs the translation from the message catalog.
VScode lists one Problem "_" is not defined...